# Google Analytics Status: Tracking Installed - but isnt working

Tags: google-analytics

**Hi I just add google analytics to a site. I used the code that google give me:**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-57032837-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**and didn't work (tracking not installed). So I search and found this one:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-57032837-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

**Now GA says: Tracking Installed (but isn't showing me any result - tracking or stadistics-)**. I must to wait? I'm doing something wrong? I'm a web designer not a developer, so some help will be great! thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up a classic GA implementation (your latter code) with a Universal Analytics one (your former code). Which version are you using? Have you already migrated your web properties to UA? I suspect that since you mentioned that you just added the code, then you're using UA. In this case, make sure you have the UA tracking code on your site (the former code). It normally takes at least 24 hours for the code to start processing data into your standard reports, at which time the status will say "Tracking not installed". If you check your real-time reports for your own visits and you can see hits there, then you should be fine, and only need to wait.

Comment: Hi nyuen thx for the quick answer, I'm using now the latter code (the second one), I don't know if you ask that when you say "which version I'm using". To be honest this is my first time using GA so I feel pretty lost. let me know how I can help you to help me. For now I don't see anything, even my own visits hits. Thx in adavanced!

Comment: Ok, I read and read again trying to clear understand what you said... So If I understand well I must to follow GA the instructions copy an paste this code:

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-57032837-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

and be patient and wait 24 hours.

Comment: I just copy and paste the code this morning so maybe my problem is not to wait enough.Just wondering even thats the solution why with the second code (latter code) the status change at the moment? Let me know If you think the solution will be return to the code GA gave me (UA) and just wai. Tx!

Comment: Use the first code (Universal Analytics), and check in Real-Time reports to see if you see your own visits. Since this is a new implementation you might as well use UA because classic GA will be phased out soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try going on your website's homepage (or any page where the code is supposed to show up), pull up the source code for the webpage (right click > "show source code" or something similar) and try searching for the GA code. Is it present?
2. If it is indeed present, go to any page where the code is implemented, and try going to your GA and check the "real time" section. The interface should show at least "1 visitor" being connected.

Comment: Yeap! It's working, Thx! I just have one last doubt! Is working and thats great, but is working with the second code I implemented, not the one that google give me, I suppose that's not ok or I wrong?

Comment: I return to the code google gave me... following nyuen comments. Tx for you help too edomt.